# How can I consume 3rd party web service using SAOP authentication in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am going develop a plugins for wordpress where I consume secured 3rd party Secure Web Service. I tried by folowing code but error said.

> "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /file/) in **url/wp-includes/option.php**"

and code is as follows

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://xyz/services/MidaService.asmx?wsdl");

// Prepare SoapHeader parameters
$sh_param = array(
'pid'    =>    '1234',  
'username'    =>    'abcd',
'password'    =>    'abcd1234567');
$headers = new SoapHeader('http://xyz/services/services', 'UserCredentials', $sh_param);

// Prepare Soap Client
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($headers));
```

What is the problem and how can I write a plugin based on web services?

Comment: You hvae a tpyo in yuor tltie. Your code looks much like [the example from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php), except that fact that you pass `$headers` wrapped in an array, can you please try it without: `$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($headers);`. Please add the PHP version you're using (edit your post).

Comment: Hi, I tried every this without header also but not succeed ...

Comment: Now It is connected with Method but nothing returns :)